# how do i write a python program that outputs the true data type of the input entered by the user?

Tags: if-statement

This is the code that I tried

x=input('enter anything')
print(type(x))#this program will only give class str

I've tried using a'try and except' structure but it is not like an if statement where i can insert multiple if statements.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` only ever returns a `str`, so `type(x)` will always be the class of `str`. It will never return a `float` or an `int` or any other type.

If you mean that you want to distinguish strings that correspond to valid literal values of other types (e.g. `"12345"` or `"3.1415"`), this is going to require different approaches.